# Design implementation of photo upload

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am building an Android application and there are five `Activity` classes or if you're familiar with the MVC pattern they would usually be the `Controller` classes.

Specifically a `User` will enter one of these 5 `Activity` classes (by navigating throughout the app) and sometimes they might upload a photo. Now the code for uploading a photo follows a very similar pattern. Please note all this code is repeated 5 times in all 5 classes (YUCK).

**Global Variables**:

```
/*
Tracking
 */
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int GET_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

private Uri mUri;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private File mFile;
private TypedFile mTypedFile; // For Retrofit
```

**User hits Photo Upload Button, and a AlertDialog pops up:**

```
private void showFileOptions() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setItems(R.array.uploadOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            dispatchTakePicture();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            dispatchUploadFromGallery();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

**dispatchTakePicture:**

```
/*
Take picture from your camera
 */
private void dispatchTakePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Make sure that there is a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        // Create the File where the mTypedFile would go
        File picFile = null;

        try {
            picFile = createImageFile();
            mFile = picFile;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Continue only if the file was successfully created
        if (picFile != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(picFile));
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

**dispatchUploadFromGallery:**

```
/*
Take a mTypedFile from your gallery
 */
private void dispatchUploadFromGallery() {
    // Launch gallery intent
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore
            .Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), GET_FROM_GALLERY);
}
```

Please note that `startActivityForResult` gets called in both of these methods. Next up is the `createImageFile()` method if the user wants to take a picture from the `Camera` API:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create the Image File name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, // Prefix
            ".jpg", // Suffix
            storageDir // Directory
    );

    // Save the file, path for ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    mUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

    return image;
}
```

Now finally our `startActivityForResult(...)` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        startUploadProgress();
        showContainer();

        mTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", mFile);
        RotatePictureHelper.rotatePicture(mFile, ExampleActivity.this, mAttachment); // Helper class to rotate pictures
        mBus.post(new LoadUploadFileEvent(mTypedFile));

    } else if (requestCode == GET_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        startUploadProgress();
        showContainer();

        mUri = data.getData();
        mTypedFile = UriHelper.handleUri(mUri, this); // Helper class to handle bitmap manipulation
        mFile = mTypedFile.file();
        mBus.post(new LoadUploadFileEvent(mTypedFile));
    } else if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.generalError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Note that I have already created helper classes to handle bitmap manipulation and picture rotation issues.

STILL, this is very ugly ugly code, and to have this repeated in 5 classes.

I have a few ideas in mind right now:

- Create a service and pass in needed variables to that service to handle this.
- Moving `AlertDialog` options to a helper class and call different `AlertDialogs` based on `instanceOf` whatever `Activity` is calling it.
- Should I create a parent `Activity` class that has these methods and then extend the 5 `Activity` child classes and call these methods?

Comment: option 3 seems the nicest, based on what you explained of your problem

Comment: Option three would be nice. It would save time and code complexity.It would reuslt in a nice and clean code.

Comment: I am leaning towards Option 3, I'll test this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I went with my 3rd option:

I created an activity called `CameraActivity` and then extended this `Activity` in my other 5 `Activity` classes. The code that each of these classes had was 95% similar with maybe 5% differences each respectively.

My `CameraActivity` would have the following code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    /*
      Tracking
     */
    private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int GET_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

    private Uri mUri;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private File mFile;
    private TypedFile mTypedFile; // For Retrofit

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        startProgress();

        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    mTypedFile = new TypedFile("image/*", mFile);
                }
                break;
            case GET_FROM_GALLERY:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    mUri = data.getData();
                    mTypedFile = UriHelper.handleUri(mUri, this);
                }
                break;
            default:
                stopProgress();
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.generalError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void showFileOptions() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setItems(R.array.uploadOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                dispatchTakePicture();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                dispatchUploadFromGallery();
                                break;
                            default:
                                dispatchUploadFromGallery();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    // Other code for handling Uri and File goes here....

}
```

Now I can extend this `Activity` in my other `Activity` classes and implement the rest of the 5% differences there. Take note that `showFileOptions()` has changed to `protected` status so I can call it from a child `Activity`. As an example here is one activity.

```
public class PhotoUploadActivity extends CameraActivity {

    // Initialize methods
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showFileOptions(); // Calling AlertDialog from Parent Activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Super call executes code in CameraActivity
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Implement logic if user take a photo, do something with mUri or mTypedFile
                }
                break;
            case GET_FROM_GALLERY:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Implement logic if user gets something from gallery, do something with mUri or mTypedFile
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Now I can simply extend my 5 child `Activity` classes call `super.onActivityResult(...)` in those classes and factor in the remainder 5% code while `CameraActivity` handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fragment which extends [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) (eg. UploadPhotoFragment), override onCreateDialog and onActivityResult methods. And when needs, call

```
(new UploadPhotoFragment()).show(getFragmentManager(), null);
```

Ps: If you are using support library, use support library's DialogFragment and FragmentManager.

Comment: Ok I can see where you are going with this, but your answer seems very simplistic. How would you handle say EventBus events and other dynamic content that might occur?

Comment: You can handle dynamic content with Bundle. UploadPhotoFragment f = new UploadPhotoFragment(); Bundle b = new Bundle(); b.putString(".."); f.setArguments(b); f.show(...);

Comment: That's a little bit like reinventing the wheel have you worked with an Eventbus before?

Comment: I assume you want to use native way. In fragment, you can use eventbus same as in activity.

Comment: It's harder to register an Otto `Bus` inside a `Fragment` you usually have to call `BusProvider.getInstance()` furthermore a `Fragment` has trouble registering for subscription events to the `EventBus`. I am still trying to figure out an efficient way for a `Fragment` to register to the `EventBus` if you have solution post it, otherwise I see no point in implementing things this way, since my activities are dependent on the `EventBus`.

Comment: When i use Otto, i don't have any trouble about registering or another thing. Do you have any issues in your project ?